# Axis emphasis in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, axis, highlight

Is there an elegant (i.e. not by writing `plot 0` with a black line) way to emphasize *OX*? In other words, to highlight part of the grid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `set xzeroaxis`:

```
set xzeroaxis lt 1 lc rgb 'black' lw 2
plot x
```

[image]